# how to download a file using broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

How do i download a file using a broadcast receiver silently in the background?
i want to download a file every time the `onReceive` is fired. also would this require asynctask? below is my code

```
package com.android.systemmanager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class FreezerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//download wallpaper here
}
}
```

i just want it to download the file in the downloads directory so that user can access it later from gallery :)

Comment: use a service inside onReceive to download

Comment: use service in background to download the file. this will silently download the file you want to download.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start a `IntentService` from Your Broadcast recieve, `beacuse there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed-`

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) doc to get started.

Comment: any snippet for this? and the download procedure ;) thanks in advance dear

Comment: @Emily read - http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: download the sample if needed from above link

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("ok","ok");
    nm = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(
            "Picture Download dnsadg sadgasjdgashgd asgd asjdg asjgd sajgd s")
            .setContentText("Download in progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_app).setContentInfo("0%");

    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);  
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/aaaa");
    String urlToDownload = "http://dl2.mid.az/endir.php?file=uploads/Exclusive/miri_yusif_-_yoxam_men_mp3.mid.az.mp3";
   // ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(root.getPath(),
                "ok.mp3"));

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            progressChange((int)(total * 100) / fileLength);
            // publishing the progress....
         //   Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
         //   resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
         //   receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
  //  resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
  //  receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("DESTROY", "DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}
void progressChange(int progress){


    if (lastupdate != progress) {
        lastupdate = progress;
        // not.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress,
        // 100,Integer.valueOf(progress[0]), false);
        // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
        // nm.notify(42, not);
        if (progress < 100) {
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, Integer.valueOf(progress),
                    false).setContentInfo(progress+"%");
            nm.notify(12, mBuilder.build());
               Intent i = new Intent("com.russian.apps.TabActivity").putExtra("some_msg",progress+"%");
                this.sendBroadcast(i);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
            // Removes the progress bar
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false).setOngoing(false).setContentInfo("");;

            nm.notify(12, mBuilder.build());

        }

    }

}
}
```

You might want to add `startForeground()` method to avoid crashes

Comment: can i paste this whole code in my onReceive method?

Comment: It won't work in your code unless you modify it according to your requirements.... It is just for reference